# Calling HBase Coprocessors from C++

Tags: c++, hbase, protocol-buffers, rpc

i need to call hbase coprocessors from c++ application. Is it even possible?
HBase 0.96.x and newer use protocol-buffers for communicationg with endpoint coprocessors. It probably should now be possible to call them explicitely from something else than Java?

The only information i could find is this:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hbase-user/201301.mbox/%3CCADfYSXQ0HMR910hUhD9mMaT2ma0vx9CDjrVWzbDrLbAsO0upNA@mail.gmail.com%3E
leading to JIRA:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-6790

and this:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-5600

Both these tickets seems kind of dead. It seems like there is no RPC, that allows to call hbase-coprocessors directly, or am i wrong?

Comment: I'm sure that this link will help you https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#services

Comment: Well this is about service definition. But what about rpc-communication implementation itself. It must communicate with hbase somehow.

Comment: From article abowe: `If you want to use your message types with an RPC (Remote Procedure Call) system, you can define an RPC service interface in a .proto file and the protocol buffer compiler will generate service interface code and **stubs** in your chosen language`. This tool will generate stub also, AFAIK it can be used on client side.

Comment: Yes, well, it creates RPC service interface. Not rpc service implementation. Im asking about "channel" for communication with hbase, not about the communication protocol.

Comment: I don't understand you. Initially you have asked about possibility to communicate with HBase from cpp side, This is possible please review `DoSearch()` method from https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#services

Comment: Yes, this is what im talking about. There is missing MyRpcChannel and MyRpcController. These 2 are the channel, thats needed on hbase side - "interface", that can i can connect to, and it understand the data sent to this interface. I dont have problems with protobuffers, and serializator. I need the rpc "facility" that allows me to communicate with hbase. Currently there are two of these "interfaces". Thrift and REST(using probably http) "interface". But none of them understands coprocessor calling.